# Solving $xdy+(y-xe^x)dx=0$ from GRE 8767.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gre-exam

I'm a little confused about GRE 8767 problem #40.

> Let $y=f(x)$ be a solution of the differential equation $xdy+(y-xe^x)dx=0$ such that $y=0$ when $x=1$. What is the value of $f(2)$?

I see that this is an exact differential since $g(x,y)=xy+e^x-xe^x+C$ is such that $g_x=y-xe^x$ and $g_y=x$. How can I use this to find $f(2)$? I tried writing
$$
g(2,f(2))=2f(2)+e^2-2e^2+C=\cdots
$$
but I'm not sure what follows. Thanks. The final answer is $e^2/2$ by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have arrived at the conclusion that for a solution $y=f(x)$ we have:
$$
   g(x, f(x)) = C
$$
Initial condition $f(1) = 0$ determines $C=0$, hence
$$
     0 = g(2, f(2)) = 2 f(2) + \mathrm{e}^2 - 2 \mathrm{e}^2 = 2 f(2) - \mathrm{e}^2
$$
Hence $f(2) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{e}^2$

Comment: Thanks Sasha. Why is $g(x,f(x))=C$ and not $g(x,f(x))=xf(x)+e^x-xe^x+K$? And can you explain how $f(1)=0$ implies $C=0$? After that I follow the rest.

Comment: You have verified that $\mathrm{d} g(x, f(x)) = 0$, thus $g(x,f(x))$ must be a constant, where $g(x,y) = x y + (1-x) \mathrm{e}^x$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand it. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Re-write the ODE by multiplying through by $dx$ to give $x \, y'(x) + y(x) - xe^x = 0$. This ODE can be solved very simply. We want to solve $xy' + y = xe^x$ which is the same as $(xy)' = xe^x$. Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives $xy = (x-1)e^x + k$ and so:

$y(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}e^x + \frac{k}{x} \, ,$

where $k$ is an arbitrary constant. If $y(1) = 0$ then $k = 0.$ The specific solution is

$y(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}e^x \, , $

and so $y(2) = \frac{1}{2}e^2.$